# MySQL Java Spring batchUpdate column name escaping

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-jdbc

I have a mysql batchUpdate using Spring named JDBC as follows:

```
public SqlParameterSource[] getBatchParamsArray(Collection params) {
    List<SqlParameterSource> dbParams = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Object p: params) {
       BeanPropertySqlParameterSource beanPropertySqlParameterSource = new      BeanPropertySqlParameterSource(p);
       dbParams.add(beanPropertySqlParameterSource);
     }
     return dbParams.toArray(new SqlParameterSource[0]);
}
```

This is used as follows:

```
String SQL = "INSERT INTO mytable (user_id, related_user_id,:tagName) VALUES (:userId,:relatedUserId,:taggedAt) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE set :tagName=:taggedAt"
this.namedJDBC.batchUpdate(SQL, this.getBatchParamsArray(listOfPOJOs));
```

My problem is that batchUpdate escapes the column name resulting in a query like so:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (tuser_id, related_user_id,'some_tag') VALUES (1234,24542336,'2015-12-17 10:44:25') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 'some_tag'='2015-12-17 10:44:25'
```

The column some_tag exists, but the escaping ' makes the SQL query fail, so how can I prevent escaping and do it manually, or otherwise achieve the desired generic functionality of batch inserts

Comment: String SQL = "INSERT INTO mytable (user_id, related_user_id,"+tagName+") VALUES (:userId,:relatedUserId,:taggedAt) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE set "+tagName+"=:taggedAt"

Comment: "+tagName+" wouldn't be replaced with the actual tag "some_tag"

Answer (score 0):

So far, it seems that's not possible, I've tried also:

```
SET @tagName='some_tag'; INSERT INTO myTable (user_id, related_user_id,@tagName) ....
```

Still the same problem.
So I resulted to this:

```
this.getConnection().setAutoCommit(false);
for(POJO t:listOfPOJOs) {
   this.namedJDBC.update(SQL.replace(":tagName",t.getTagName()), new BeanPropertySqlParameterSource(t));
}
this.getConnection().setAutoCommit(true);
```

As such appreciate your feedback here!